# How to view external library's source in a Rust project in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

When working on Rust projects in IntelliJ IDEA, the IDE provides a project view with access to external library sources:

[image: project view with access to external library sources]

This is configurable at the import or creation of a Rust project.

[image: configuration]

Does this feature exist in a Visual Studio Code Rust project workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a built in feature, but you can use right click, Go to definition (<kbd>F12</kbd>).

For example: `use std::io::BufReader;` right-click <kbd>F12</kbd> on `BufReader` opens up the file `buffered.rs` with the definition.

Answer (score 0):

The `rust-analyzer` extension enables this.

[image]